# How to solve this wood/string/ring puzzle

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, solvability

When I was living in Argentina, I encountered this puzzle:

[image: wood block puzzle with two holes and two rings, with string threaded through the holes and the rings]

I believe the goal is to somehow free the string so it only passes through the small hole in the side (at the right in this image; somewhat difficult to see).  I played with it for weeks but I never figured it out.

Is this the correct goal for this puzzle?  How is it solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Looks like the goal is to
>  separate the rings so that they are at opposite ends
>  of the block's tunnel (small hole).
>  
>  [image]

If so, it is equivalent to another puzzle in reverse,
whose solution can be seen
[as diagrams](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/jbstringring.htm)
or in a
[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkGI9rHIGZk).

> [[image] String and Ring Puzzle](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/jbstringring.htm)
>  (diagrams)
>  
>  [[image] How to do the String and Ring Puzzle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkGI9rHIGZk)
>  (video)

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to free the string from the 2 holes on the left

> you take the loop formed by the rope exiting from the center hole, you move it to the left, you open it and you move it under the left end of the wood, you pass it to the right (passing under the wood). It will look like if you're moving the wood piece into the loop.
>   This is the best I could draw...
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
>  Once passed to the right completely, you pull it up. The loop is now free and you can pull it through the center hole and then through the left hole.